# Extract CSV headers and display on HTML page

Tags: javascript, database, csv, flat-file

Wondering if you can help me,

I have some CSV files which are scheduled to land in a directory on my server on an hourly basis.

Ideally, I'd like to read these files, extract the headers and print those headers on my web page.

So, I am looking for a javascript function, which can extract the CSV headers and display them in my HTML file

Does anyone have any idea how I could do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try js-xlsx here -> https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **get** request using Jquery: 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "yourfile.csv",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {processFileData(data);}
         });
    });

in processFileData iterate through the lines (split text by 'r/n') and split each row by coma (',').

Comment: The next person I see split a CSV file on the commas is gonna catch a beatdown from a CSV parser.